# Why does pre_c_init access memory outside of the defined program segments?

Tags: c++, assembly, exe, portable-executable

While looking through the assembly for a console "hello world" program (compiled using the visual c++ compiler), I came across this:

```
 pre_c_init      proc near
.text:00401AFE                 mov     eax, 5A4Dh
.text:00401B03                 cmp     ds:400000h, ax
```

The code above seems to be accessing memory that isn't filled with anything in particular: All segments start at 0x401000 or even further down in the file. (The image base is at 0x400000, but the first segment is at 0x401000).

I used OllyDbg to see what the actual value at 0x400000 is, and every single time it's the same as in the code (0x5A4D). What's going on here?

Comment: Looks like it's validating the signature bytes of the EXE header.

Comment: Sure, it seems like that's what it does. Is it actually normal for windows to just dump the first 0x1000 bytes of the header at the image base location?

Comment: Yes, it's normal. The header is part of the executable image and loaded into memory.

Answer (score 1):

`5A4D` is "MZ" in little-endian ASCII, and MZ is the [signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957057/what-is-the-mz-signature-in-a-pe-file-for) of MS-DOS and, more recently, PE executables.

The comparison checks whether the executable has been mapped at the default base address, 0x400000. This, I believe, is used to determine whether it is necessary to perform [relocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)).

This is discussed further in the following thread: [Why does PE need a relocation table?](http://www.asmcommunity.net/forums/topic/?id=28027)

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but this code is executed after all the relocations have been done (it's one of the functions that _initterm_e calls). Furthermore, the relocation table actually contains a reference to the pointer. Also, the file does not directly map to memory, correct? If there's no section in the PE headers defined for this location, what should it contain?